# Regex map properties of an object in C# class in Find and replace window

Tags: c#, regex, mapping

We are manually mapping object properties from a source object to the target object in our project. 
Below is a simple example (please note property names on both sides are always the same):

```
public class Source {
    public string FirstName {gets; set;}
}

public class Target{
    public string FirstName {gets; set;}
}

public Target Map(Source source, Target target){
   source.FirstName = target.FirstName;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is copy property definition from one of the classes (either source or target in to my mapping method, like this:

```
public Target Map(Source source, Target target){
   public string FirstName {gets; set;}
}
```

and then use Regex to replace

```
public string FirstName {gets; set;}
```

With

```
source.FirstName = target.FirstName;
```

By selecting all properties in Visual studio and running regex in find and replace window.

Thanks for your help.
Alex

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? And I'm not sure if this is possible with Find/Replace since it isn't a Find/Replace operation.

Comment: Writing the Regex, I found questionhere on Stackoverflow 2 years ago and the answer was working fine, could not find it any more so I asked again.

Comment: I mean, the second half is doable, but the first half doesn't seem like something regex can do.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, Im trying to use regex to convert                        
```public string FirstName {gets; set;}``` to
```source.FirstName = target.FirstName;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before using regex expression you should understand how it works :  "The backslash character".
I think here is what you need(I like first one),

`public[\s]+string[\s]+FirstName[\s]+\{[\s]*gets\;[\s]*set\;[\s]*\}`

or

`public\s{1}string\s{1}FirstName\s+\{{1}\s*gets\;\s*set\;\s*\}`

---

Let's separate first case to understand easily as below,
public`[\s]+`string`[\s]+`FirstName`[\s]+` `\{` `[\s]*`gets`\;` `[\s]*`set`\;` `[\s]*\}`

And let's focus at the first and second words.

> `\S` is Matches any **white-space** character.
>   `\s` is Matches any **non-white-space** character.
>   `[ character_group_can_be_here ]` is Matches any single character in character_group. By default, the match is case-sensitive.

So,
`[\s]+` or `\s+` : Matches any white-space character character. **one and more**.
`\s{1}` : Matches any white-space character character. just **one**.

Also,
    Between `public(keywork)` and `string(type)`should separated one and more space character.

Further information :[Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio)